# PHP reservation system passing specific while loop results to next php page

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, system

Making a car rental reservation system for a school project, project is in html/php & SQL. So far the user picks location date/time and car category on page 1, user then searches available cars on page 2. on page 2 the cars are listed and user picks the car they want to rent, the cars are listed in while loop from 
the database. there is a reserve button attached to each car so that the user can pick.

Heres my issue how do i pass over the cars details as variables(make, model, class, dailyrate) for what the user picks onto the next php page prompting page. im using $_sessions.

```
    <?php 

    $sql= "SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE class='$class'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($resultCheck > 0) {
             while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {   //beginning of while loop

                $_SESSION['make']=$row['make'];
                $_SESSION['model']=$row['model'];
                $_SESSION['class']=$row['class']; 
                $_SESSION['dailyrate']=$row['daily_rate'];

             ?>

                <div class="card">
                   <div class="img">
                    <img src='../../images/defaultcar.png' width='100' height='100'>
                   </div>
                   <div>
                        Make: <?php  echo $row['make']; ?><br>
                        Model: <?php echo $row['model']; ?><br>
                        <b>Class: <?php echo $row['class']; ?></b><br>
                       <div class="price"> <b>$ <?php echo $row['daily_rate']; ?></b>/Per day</div>
                   </div>

                <a href="booking-payment.php"><button class='reserve-btn'>Reserve</button></a>

                </div>;

             <?php  } //ending bracket of while loop
        }
        else { 
                echo "0 results"; 
             }
    ?>      
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will try to help you through google translate, the easiest way to do it is by adding the car ID in the value of the reserve button, then declare a name for the button and send that ID to the next page, getting there only from another SELECT * FROM CARS WHERE ID =? and get the information

Comment: thank you! im trying it out! in the Query statement you provided after '=' what do i put?